# Our tomcat just crashed due to classnotfound, not sure how to investigate

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

Our server has been in production for years without issues, but today it crashed out of the blue.

Last in the logs:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aasxknsakadskdskdskdsakmxxads
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: aasknsakadskdskdskdsakmads
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)

Could not find the main class: aasxknsakadskdskdskdsakxxmads. Program will exit.
```

While its obvious what caused the crash, i have no clue as to why. We have no new production code, nothing has changed as far as we know. I'm not sure how to investigate this, to me it seems like some sort of dynamic class-loading hack attempt?

I'm at a loss so any pointers on how to investigate / prevent this would be extremely appreciated.

Tomcat/6.0.28

Comment: Look earlier in the logs - any reload? Anything not usual? Check access logs for URLs that aren't part of your regular application calls.

Comment: Have you changed the class name to "aasxknsakadskdskdskdsakmxxads" to post on SO? Or is that actually what's being printed out? If the missing class is a real "com.company..." then perhaps a .class file has been accidentally deleted?

Comment: Hey, well i did change it a bit, but it basically looks like that. No package info. Thats one of the reasons its freaking me out a bit.